# Protect your Google Play public key - Solution

Tags: android, security

How to protect your public key:

```
private static byte[] xor(final byte[] input, final byte[] secret) {
  final byte[] output = new byte[input.length];
  if (secret.length == 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty security key");
  }
  int spos = 0;
  for (int pos = 0; pos < input.length; ++pos) {
    output[pos] = (byte) (input[pos] ^ secret[spos]);
    ++spos;
    if (spos >= secret.length) {
        spos = 0;
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

This chunk of code looks great and it works ok. But my question is how exactly to use it?

My thinking is like this: Create a "secret"

1. create encode string with code above and hardcode it.
2. on runtime decode this encoded string.
   Every time use the same secret and the same algorithm.

My question is where to hide secret, that potential hacker wount be able to get my public key. Because if the secret is also hardcoded and algorithm is known... Well he will get my public key.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to protect a public key (maybe you mean *private* key?), after all, public keys are intended to be public.  Putting that aside, no the code is not as great as you think.  It is a variant of the [Vigenere cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), which is not very secure.  These ciphers are not difficult to crack, and become especially easy when you encrypt more than one thing with the same key.  You'd be much better off using the AES in CBC mode than something like this.

I assume the [Android Key Store](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) is not an option for you.

Hard coding a secret in your code is going to fall pretty quickly to reverse engineering unless you use something like [Arxan](https://www.arxan.com/what-we-do/how-we-protect-apps/) or [Dexguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard).